# onRequestPermissionsResult is called infinitely

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I'm using a runtime permission request, but there is a problem with that. It seems that the callback method `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called infinitely. So when the user denies the request the app is unresponsive..

the permission dialog reappears everytime the user clicks 'deny'. Only by clicking "never ask again" does it not reappear again.
* When pressing 'allow' it works well - without any problems.

Is there any way to cancel the method being invoked after one time?

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CUSTOM_REQUEST_CODE );
}


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch( requestCode )
        {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_CUSTOM_REQUEST_CODE:   
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted
                    MyManager.connect();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // permission denied
                    return;
                }
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens in MyManager.connect()?

Comment: @GilMoshayof just `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` . Also, It's worth mentioning that If  "allow" is clicked, then the problem doesn't occur. But when user presses 'deny' it inifintely calles `onRequestPermissionsResult `

Comment: By the way, the permission dialog reappears everytime you click 'deny'. Only by click "never ask again" does it not reappear again

Comment: Could you show where your "if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission...)" code is running? What method is this code inside?

Comment: I think I found the problem! it happens only when I call the permission request in the `onResume`. Do you know why by any chance? Or is it just a bug that Google should fix?

Comment: Yes, of course - onResume is called when another activity finishes and returns to the current activity. The request permission dialog acts as an activity, so when it stops working, your current activity is resumed, and thus the cycle repeats :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem here, as you mentioned in the comments, is that the code that triggers the request permission dialog is being called in the `onResume` method.

When the request dialog permission finishes, the runtime calls `onResume` on the activity that triggered it, just as any dialog-themed activity would.

In your case, refusing the permission would trigger a call to `onResume` again, which would once again display the dialog and cause an endless cycle.

Moving this permission request to `onCreate`, or some other flow will solve your problem.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: "just as any dialog would" -- that is true for a dialog-themed activity. It is not true for a `Dialog`, as a `Dialog` does not affect the activity lifecycle. In this case, the runtime permissions dialog is a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: for me, biggest problem currently is that calling `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` returns `false` after clicking on `Don't allow` on android 13 :(